# EXTJS map array of strings to model field values

Tags: json, extjs

I am using EXT JS 4.1.1.

I have a json response like this:

```
{ values: ["A","B","C"] }
```

I then have a model like so:

```
Ext4.define('model', {
    extends: 'Ext4.data.model',
    fields: [ 'name' ]
});
```

I am trying to create models with one value, `name`, that corresponds to the above json `values` so that I can use the `name` values in a ComboBox.

```
Ext4.define('store',{
    extend: 'Ext4.data.Store',
    model: 'model',
    requires: 'model',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'values',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

The issue I'm having is that when populating my ComboBox with the `name` attribute, it is empty (`""`). The `raw` value is correct, it corresponds directly to the appropriate value.

How can I map this array of values correctly to a `name` field on my `model` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not actually a proper JSON response, paste it into http://jsonlint.com/ and you will see for yourself.

Instead your JSON should look like this:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "name": "A"
        },
        {
            "name": "B"
        },
        {
            "name": "C"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which you will see is valid if you paste into the jsonlint link above.

The store reader is expecting to see 'name' attributes in the data, but cannot, which is why you are seeing this behaviour.

Comment: Actually, http://jsonlint.com/ just accuses his JSON is not valid due to the absence of quotes on "values" key.

{ "values": ["A", "B", "C"] } is a valid JSON, for example.